# Bring network interface down if physical connectivity is lost

Tags: ip, route

I have a headless Debian server with two network cards:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 01:02:1d:54:7c:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 01:02:1d:54:7e:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

If I disconnect the cable connected to `eth1`, then port will go down, but administratively it will stay up:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 01:02:1d:54:7c:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
2: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 01:02:1d:54:7e:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This means that routes associated with `eth1` are still present in routing table. Is there a way to force `eth1` administratively down once it's physically disconnected?

Comment: What if you then reconnect? It should also be able to detect that and bring the card back up, right?

Comment: @terdon Yes, it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to use `ip monitor` and a script that "ifupdowns" the interface.

The script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

ip monitor link | while IFS=':' read num name status; do
    read extraline # iproute2 outputs physical address on a separate line.
    newstate=$(echo "$status"|awk -F' ' '{print $NF}')
    if [ "$newstate" = "UP" ]; then
        ifup "$name"
    elif [ "$newstate" = "DOWN" ]; then
        ifdown "$name"
    fi
done
```

The script doesn't check network interface status before attempting to change it, but that shouldn't be a problem.

To use it just place it in `/opt/bin/linkmonitor.sh`, make it executable with `chmod +x /opt/bin/linkmonitor.sh` and add it to `/etc/rc.local` with an ampersand at the end:

```
/opt/bin/linkmonitor.sh &
```

If you need a more robust solution you may be interested in a [route failover](http://archive09.linux.com/articles/113988) solution.

Comment: Thanks! Not that I have anything against custom-made scripts based on `ip monitor`, I thought that this is so common problem that there is some sort of daemon for this.

Comment: Sure, it's called networkmanager :p

Comment: :D I thought something more suitable for servers. However, I'll go with the `ip monitor` script. Thanks!